# What should I do to get my Blender models into my iOS game?

Tags: 3d, opengl-es, ios, blender

I am working on a 3D OpenGL|ES game for iPad. All the models are created in Blender. How should I go about getting my models into my game?

I have the following requirements of my models:

1. One texture map
2. Material
3. Skeletal animation data
4. Attachables / Socket Points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a file format readable on iOS, which technically is anything, but if you need a place to start the PowerVR SDK has tools for making and reading POD files.

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-sdk.asp

Be sure to grab the correct SDK depending on the OpenGL ES version you are targeting (OpenGL ES 1.1 if you don't know yet).

From Blender 2.5+ you can export to Collada (DAE) files, then import them in to this to make PODs:

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-collada2pod.asp

Comment: Newer versions of the SDK have an exporter for recent versions of Blender, so you don't need to export to COLLADA first.

Answer (score -3):

Use this script in blender
http://www.innerloop.biz/code/objc.py.zip

Then look at this sample project
http://innerloop.biz/code/ExportTest.zip

Comment: -1; it'd be nice if your answer explained the approach rather than asking people to blindly download .zip files (which may go away in the future, rendering this answer useless).

Comment: well geeze.. you can just google that information

Comment: The purpose of this site is to be a repository of questions and their answers, and to that end, "just Google for it," is rarely a good answer on its own. Furthermore it's actually difficult to Google for the content, purpose and use of the linked scripts.

Comment: the innerloop server is down. Where is the mirror?